# Delete keyframes quickly without the menu in timeline

Tags: keyframes, shortcut, timeline

I want to delete keyframes by pressing <kbd>X</kbd> without the "menu".
How can I block that menu?

I looked at the keymap editor, I thought, maybe the key is "DOPESHEET_MT_delete" code but I'm stuck.

There must be a new hotkey for this, that users can choose.

Answer (score 0):

- When the menu opens up, right click on "Delete Keyframes" and assign a shortcut.
- In the keymap editor, disable the "Confirm" option for the newly added keymap item.
- Remove the existing `X` delete keymap item in the keymap editor.